# Clean install 18.04 over partial install 18.04

Tags: upgrade, 18.04, libraries

Is it possible to perform a clean install 18.04 over a partial upgrade 18.04.  The problem is after 16.04 upgrade to 18.04, the system presents too many problems in running apps, this has forced me to fix too many things.
I am now exploring a clean install redeploy apps + backups.

Everything seems to work ok on 18.04 but apps are having a hard time to find libraries.
This is a dual boot Linux + win 7 so don't want to upset the working Win 7

Questions:
1. Will it use the same partitions and grub or will it require new partitions?
2. Is there any command to do a clean install/upgrade/fix from current 18.04?

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: Use the same partitions , do not format the partition with /home on it, and do a fresh install